# How to add installed WebSphere server to IRAD?

Tags: websphere

I have IRAD (Rational Application Developer) 9 installed, and I have an old WebSphere server 7 installed to `C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v7`. I want to import that server to IRAD 9's list of servers so that I can use it to locally run applications.

How do I "import" that to IRAD 9?

Comment: Thank you for the corrections sideshowbarker!

Comment: How about `New > Server` in the `Servers` view?

Comment: I tried that but it only gave the option to create a WAS 8.5 server

Comment: So it looks like you dont have testing environment for WAS v7 installed. You have to run Installation Manager, and modify RAD installation to include WAS v7 TE. By default it installs only the latest one - v8.5

Comment: I have IRAD 8 and WAS 7 installed in a folder called SDP then IRAD 9 is installed in SDP_1

Comment: It doesnt matter that you have WAS v7 installed separately, You have to have WAS v7 adapter installed in RAD. Run that installation Manager and check that you dont have WAS7 environment installed. Maybe you installed it with RAD8, but you need adapter in RAD 9 also

Comment: Great! I will give that a shot.